# SSH takes too long to ask for password

Tags: debian, ssh, networking, dns, sshd

I've seen many other questions on this subject but none seem to actually solve my problem. Like any other day, I connect to my LOCAL Raspberry Pi server from my client machine at 192.168.0.5 with `ssh pi@192.168.0.4`. I then have to wait around 4 to 5 seconds before getting a `Password:` prompt.

By reading other questions I have found various papered fixes such as setting `UseDNS` to No in Server SSHD_CONFIG file. This does work and fixes my problem, giving me the password prompt almost instantly but this does not fix my problem in the sense of fixing the actual DNS. I thought because this was on my local network that it did not require reverse lookup?

Answer (score 2):

Sshd doesn't care where the connection is coming from, if it's configured to do a reverse DNS lookup, it does.

Comment: Yes, but there is obviously something wrong here. Here is the contents of my resolv.conf file `domain Home
nameserver 192.168.0.1`

Comment: I was just responding to the last sentence, while trying to figure out what think about the DNS issue, because I have a similar setup here where I don't get such a delay.

Comment: Well it looks as if my router uses DHCP and forwards DNS to my ISP (Sky Broadband), unfortunately there is no option to change DNS servers in Router firmware to google DNS. I'm trying to find out how to change static DNS in raspbian